# How to launch AWS Batch job with dependency on an ECS task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-batch

The AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/job_dependencies.html) explains how to launch multiple AWS Batch jobs that depend on one another.

How can I launch a **Batch job**, subject to depending on an (indepdently launched) **ECS task** to complete, first?

I tried to paste the ECS **task** ARN as the job ID, but that failed. The Batch job started right away. Is the only solution to submit *all* the jobs that you want in your depedency chain through AWS Batch, so they will have an AWS Batch job ID (even if the job will always have array size == 1)? Or is there a shortcut to feed a **task ID** into the job dependency?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to tell Batch to wait for a non-Batch ECS task. You should look into [AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html) if you need to orchestrate multiple AWS services that depend on each other to perform tasks in order.

Comment: To add some color - an ECS task ID is different than a Batch job ID. The reason for this is that Batch may retry your job, which results in a different ECS task ID but the same Batch job ID so you can keep track of the retries. +1 to using Step Functions for the dependencies across ECS and Batch